# Illegal Argument Exception when trying to convert byte to Bitmap in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Here is my code where i am getting profile image bytes from twitter api,

```java
new Thread() {

    public void run() {
        byte dbata[] = getBitmap(profle_pic_str);
        if (dbata != null) {
            EncodedImage bitmap_img = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(dbata, 0, -1);
            Bitmap image =bitmap_img.getBitmap();
            final Bitmap profle_pic_bmp = image;
            final Bitmap scld_bmp = new Bitmap(90, 100);
            Application.getApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (profle_pic_bmp != null) {
                        profle_pic_bmp.scaleInto(scld_bmp, Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS);
                        phot_profle.setBitmap(scld_bmp);
                    } else {
                        Dialog.alert("null");
                    }
                }
            });
        // } else {
            // Dialog.alert("bytes are null");
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Here i have method getBitmap(profle_pic_str); which returning bytes array of image,

```java
public byte[] getBitmap(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    String strg = HttpConnector.getConnectionString();
    byte b[] = null;
    try {
        b = getXML(url + strg);
    } catch (IOException ie) {
        ie.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b;
}
```

the url which i used is this one

http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=screen_nameof_user&size=bigger

```java
public byte[] getXML(String url) throws IOException {
    ContentConnection connection = 
        (ContentConnection) javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(url);
    java.io.DataInputStream iStrm = connection.openDataInputStream();
    java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream bStrm = null;
    byte xmlData[] = null;
    try {
        // ContentConnection includes a length method
        int length = (int) connection.getLength();
        if (length != -1) {
            xmlData = new byte[length];
            // Read the png into an array
            // iStrm.read(imageData);
            iStrm.readFully(xmlData);
        } else // Length not available...
        {
            bStrm = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int ch;
            while ((ch = iStrm.read()) != -1) bStrm.write(ch);
            xmlData = bStrm.toByteArray();
            bStrm.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Clean up
        if (iStrm != null) iStrm.close();
        if (connection != null) connection.close();
        if (bStrm != null) bStrm.close();
    }
    return xmlData;
}
```

When i am trying to convert byte array to  EncodedImage

```java
EncodedImage  bitmap_img = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(dbata, 0, -1);
```

in this line of code i am getting illegal argument exception.

same code is working for Facebook profile image. I dont know why this code giving error when i am doing for twitter. Please help me friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

```
EncodedImage _encoded_img = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(dbata, 0, dbata.length);
```

On your code,

```
EncodedImage bitmap_img = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(dbata, 0,-1);
```

-1 is the length of the array.  Its not static. Change -1 to dbata.length.

Comment: you getting values in dbata ?

Comment: this same line EncodedImage _encoded_img = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(dbata, 0, dbata.length);

Comment: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=screen_nameof_user&size=bigger this is the url i am using

Comment: there is no image in this url

Comment: dude, i have to append twiiter screen name of twiiter, because of security purpose i have hided it.

Comment: when you call the url, then you will get the image url na ?  like - https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/22222222/IMG_2439_bigger.jpg

Comment: so you have to call this url again. so you will get the data of this url.

Comment: I tried, even i am facing same problem. What about this url, same problem coming with this also http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/twitterapi.png

Comment: https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2284174872/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png when you call this URL, you will get image.

Comment: on above ur url access denied coming.

Comment: Maybe you're missing some HTTP headers (auth or cookies or referer)

Comment: check my blog http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2012/04/display-image-from-url-in-bb.html

Comment: Hi @BlackPearl I have used ur blog code, its worked super, thanks for sharing your code with me.